# Remove AtomicInteger counter from stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, declarative

is it possible to achieve the same functionality with the code below but without using the AtomicInteger counter, or as a matter of fact, no counter at all? This code controls the order in which certain areas in the front end of my project can be completed. If `isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)` is `true`, then the first element from the `dataList` - the IData elements in dataList are converted to Data and then a list of Data is sent back as an HTTP response, to the front end -   must be handled and then only after it has been handled the second item in the dataList will become available for processing and modification, hence why I added that counter. But I would like to keep the stream and yet somehow achieve the same result, as to when I have the counter. Can it somehow be removed and the stream modified in a way that will allow me to not alter my functionality and to not go back at using conventional for loop?

Thank you

```
public List<Data> toData(List<Idata> dataList, String name) {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    List<Data> data= dataList.stream().sorted().map(input -> {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null for IData");
        }
        if (counter.get() == 0 && !input.getStatus().equals(DataStatus.COMPLETE)) {
            counter.compareAndSet(counter.get(), counter.get() + 1);
            return populateDataFields(input,true); //JUST a method that populates fiedls
        }
        if (isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)) {
            return populateDataFields(input,false);
        }
        return populateDataFields(input,true);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    counter.set(0);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a state machine. State `0` is sort of "ready to process" and non-zero is "block unti ready"

Comment: Sort of. The Data object has a canBeCompleted boolean field that is set to true only if the previous Data object has status COMPLETED. If the strict signing order is enabled then the first time this method is accessed only the top element in the list is assigned with canBeCompleted=true. Then if in the front end we complete it, then the next element in the list will be assinged to true and so on

Comment: Is it possible to modify this code, without losing the use of modern java 8+ style?

Comment: Probably. I'm trying to work out the logic.

Comment: I don't think it's a good choice to solve your issue in func style. Standart `forEach` solution should quit clear

Comment: Honestly, this steam-implementation is very hard to understand and is counter-intuitive. I think you should define (in words) what your *actual* goal is. This code looks like the underlying problem is not understood well enough to write a clean implementation. Why `populateDataFields` is called 3x with different arguments? Why do you want to use streams for (perhaps) a problem they are not suited for? Could you process the "first" element in an initial stage and then the rest of the elements in a second stage? Resetting the counter at the end of the method is not necessary.

Comment: Hmm, the more I think about it, the more I think what you have here is essentially what you need. Effectively, you're trying to do a stateful mapping operation where you have to take into account some condition that's outside of the current element only. You can make your mapper an actual state machine that moves between states but might be an overkill here. You can also turn it around into a reduce operation where your accumulator has your extra context but that's a bit weird to do in Java.  Unless I'm missing some approach or doesn't seem a stream approach is cleaner.

Comment: I guess minor cleanup can be done in few areas: the AtomicInteger can be swapped for AtomicBoolean (after all, the only numbers that matter are zero and non-zero, which is the same as having false and true). Also, it'd be good if the null check wasn't there (I wouldn't expect mapping to also do validation). It can be moved elsewhere to ensure the data you currently have is correct.  But these are quite small.

Comment: @VLAZ can you please show me how to do the reduce?

Comment: @HansBurges the easiest way is to reduce with a Pair (many implementations for those exist) as an accumulator where one (say, the first) item is the list you're appending to and the second item in the pair is a boolean. You then do a reduction with mapping at the same time and instead of maintaining an external variable for true/false (or non-zero/zero) you use the one in the accumulator. Alternatively, you make a class that has something like `result` and `state` fields but use the same idea. But whatever you use, it's not very convenient IMO. It's just the functional solution here.

Comment: Argh, I remembered the Java terminology where "accumulator" is actually a BiFunction. I'm used to calling this the "reducer", while the accumulator is the value returned from that function.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is incomprehensible. At which point are you sending an HTTP response and how does it relate to the code you’ve shown? Your stream operation is invoking the same method for every element, only the boolean parameter may differ. The second part, `if(isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)) { return populateDataFields(input,false); } return populateDataFields(input,true);` is not different to `return populateDataFields(input, !isAutomaticDataEnabled(name));` When `isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)` is `false`, the parameter will always be `true` anyway, obsoleting the `counter` logic.

Comment: I was just describing the overall logic. My question is how to achieve the same functionality demonstrated in the method posted, without getting rid of the stream.

Comment: Also, yes the same method is invoked but with different boolean value passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are always performing the same operation, only the `boolean` parameter value passed to the `populateDataFields` method differs.

If `isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)` evaluates to `false`, you are always passing `true` to the method and everything you do with the `AtomicInteger` is actually obsolete. The simplest thing you can do, is to check this condition before the stream operation and perform a straight-forward operation, always passing `true` to the `populateDataFields` method.

In the other case, you are passing `true` only for the first item in encounter order for which `input.getStatus().equals(DataStatus.COMPLETE)` evaluates to `false`. The only way to do this without depending on the processing order, is to identify the affected element first. Since both, the identification of this element and the result list, depend on the result of the sort operation, the sorting has to take place before it.

```java
public List<Data> toData(List<Idata> dataList, String name) {
    if(isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)) {
        dataList = new ArrayList<>(dataList);
        dataList.sort(null);
        Idata firstNotComplete = dataList.stream()
            .filter(input -> !input.getStatus().equals(DataStatus.COMPLETE))
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
        return dataList.stream().sorted()
            .map(input -> populateDataFields(input, input == firstNotComplete))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    else return dataList.stream().sorted()
        .map(input -> populateDataFields(input, true))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

An alternative with less redundancy is

```java
public List<Data> toData(List<Idata> dataList, String name) {
    dataList = new ArrayList<>(dataList);
    dataList.sort(null);
    Predicate<Idata> p = isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)? dataList.stream()
        .filter(input -> !input.getStatus().equals(DataStatus.COMPLETE))
        .findFirst().map(Predicate::<Idata>isEqual).orElse(x -> false): x -> true;
    return dataList.stream()
        .map(input -> populateDataFields(input, p.test(input)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Though the first variant might be slightly more efficient when `isAutomaticDataEnabled(name)` is `false`.

Note that when `DataStatus` is an `enum` type, you can simply write `input.getStatus() != DataStatus.COMPLETE` instead of `!input.getStatus().equals(DataStatus.COMPLETE)`.